# adding s3 event to SQS queue Error: Unable to validate the following destination

Tags: amazon-web-services, yaml, serverless

Trying to create a serverless automation by creating a S3 service that will trigger an event every time a csv file is uploaded and send it to SQS. Right now I was able to create all resources just fine. Even s3 is being created. However, the block of code under `NotificationConfiguration` is what is actually crashing

Right now this is what I have:

```
service: ms-test

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs12.x
  stage: ${opt:stage, 'dev'}
  region: us-east-1

resources:
  Resources:
    testQueue:
      Type: AWS::SQS::Queue
      Properties:
        DelaySeconds: 0
        MaximumMessageSize: 262144
        MessageRetentionPeriod: 1209600
        QueueName: ${self:provider.stage}-testConsumer   
        ReceiveMessageWaitTimeSeconds: 0
        VisibilityTimeout: 5400

    S3EventQueuePolicy:
      Type: AWS::SQS::QueuePolicy
      DependsOn: testQueue
      Properties:
        PolicyDocument:
          Id: SQSPolicy
          Statement:
            - Effect: Allow
              Action: SQS:SendMessage
              Resource:
                Fn::GetAtt: 
                  - "testQueue"
                  - "Arn"
              Condition:
                ArnLike:
                  aws:SourceArn: arn:aws:s3:us-east-1:::${self:provider.stage}-testBucket
        Queues:
          - Ref: testQueue

    testBucket:
      Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
      Properties:
        BucketName: ${self:provider.stage}-testBucket
        AccessControl: Private
        CorsConfiguration:
          CorsRules:
            -
              AllowedMethods:
                - "PUT"
                - "POST"
                - "GET" 
                - "DELETE"
                - "HEAD"
              AllowedOrigins:
                - "*"
        NotificationConfiguration:
          QueueConfigurations:
            - Event: s3:ObjectCreated:*
               Filter:   
                 S3Key: 
                   Rules: 
                     - Name: suffix
                       Value: .csv
              Queue: arn:aws:sqs:us-east-1:302082700830:${self:provider.stage}-testConsumer
```

However, I am receiving this error: `An error occurred: testBucket - Unable to validate the following destination configurations (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidArgument; Request ID: D1359608708E5F4D; S3 Extended Request ID: aD6Lx0/DHbejSHoXcYdFluaIcaNTZ5UByv+W+4WiWjtipLeLHPb0kmX6xX/n1pxBtECPc3FzE9g=; Proxy: null).`

Can anyone help with this?